# optimizing sbcl vector addition

Tags: common-lisp

I tried optimizing a function, that adds vectors. I made two different versions:

```
(defun v+.1 (&rest vectors)
  (apply #'map 'vector #'+ vectors))

(defun v+.2 (&rest vectors)
  (apply #'map-vector #'+ vectors))
;;where #'map-vector is a self-written function, that only works for vectors
```

`#'v+.2` is faster than `#'v+.1`, even if I use ftype- or inline-declamations.
But when I call `(map 'vector #'+ x ...)` and `(map-vector #' x ...)` where `x` ... are vectors or typed variables, without a function around it, where types are declared more precisely, then map gets much faster, and my own version gets a bit slower.

Why and what could I do, to get the speed of map when used in special functions I often use? (more type-declarations etc.?)
It should not be a macro, in case I want to use apply etc.

Comment: Are you sure that the performance difference does matter? IOW, is this _the_ bottleneck?

Comment: For your [optimization qualities](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/d_optimi.htm), do you have speed set to 3 and the others to 0?

Comment: Could you specify CL implementation and provide code for `map-vector`? If you use SBCL, you can also check result assembler with `#'disassemble` for both your versions.